# Check division is integer or float solidity

Tags: solidity, erc-20

Suppose i have a contract with decimals and total Supply as follow.
How can i check if tokenAmountInWei pass in is integer value in form of ether.

decimals = 18 
totalSupply = 1000000

```
function someFunction(uint tokenAmountInWei) {
    // check if tokenAmountInWei convert to ether is integer value
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {

    function checkIntegerETH(uint a) public pure returns (bool) {
        return (a % 1 ether == 0);
    }
}
```

Here we are basically confirming that `a` has no remainder when being divided by 10<sup>18</sup> (`1 ether`).